# Issues with populating arrays from csv(dsv) parsing

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I am quite new to javascript, basically using it for the first time to write a histogram plotter application. My issue is, I am importing a data file and ideally sending (some of) the entries into an array. Problem is that once I do that, I have troubles accessing the entries in my array.
How could I fix that? Posting the code below in case it helps.
Thank you!

```
let filename = 'uploads/testdata.dat';
    const data_e = new Array();
    d3.dsv(" ",filename, (event)=>{
        data_e.push(event.mass);
        return data_e
    })

console.log(data_e);
```

Which outputs

```
    Array []
​
     0: "734.770828169"
​
     1: "85.0912893849"
​
     2: "87.383924186"
​
     ...
```

However if I wanna get a value:
`console.log(data_e[0]) //output: undefined`

Edit1: the values I'm pushing are in `console.log(event.mass)`.
output:

```
734.770828169 analyzer.php:19:12
85.0912893849 analyzer.php:19:12
87.383924186 analyzer.php:19:12
(...)
```

Edit2: If I call console.log(data_e) inside the dsv function I get a line for each  iteration while my array gets filled, ending with

```
Array(7178) [ "734.770828169", "85.0912893849", "87.383924186", "1274.99805502", "91.5349415148", "80.2766459668", "1396.69489276", "91.5584443363", "94.52017453", "1582.29197222", … ]
```

Which is, indeed the object I want to get. But what if I want to carry that outside the function `dsv()`, so that I get the same output as above?

Edit3: Calling `console.log(JSON.stringify(event.mass))` gives:

- again, one line for each 'iteration' (I think), and it makes sense. I just want to use the full array outside that function (or maybe it's just a silly thing to do .-.)

```
"734.770828169" analyzer.php:19:12
"85.0912893849" analyzer.php:19:12
"87.383924186" analyzer.php:19:12
"1274.99805502" analyzer.php:19:12
(...)
```

Comment: Please, provide the output of `console.log(event.mass)`. If you don't want to show live data, you can obfuscate it by dummy entries. I just want to examine the structure

Comment: Edited with the output, it's just a series of numerical data (probably as strings, but that's fixable later)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `return` inside the loop, because you then leave it immediately. Whatsmore, I think `d3.dsv()` is an asynchronous function. Means your console log outside this method must return `undefined` as Javascript does not wait for `d3.dsv()` to finish. And your Array `data_e` is currently undefined.

```
let data_e = new Array();
```

Instantiate it this way and you'll see, that `console.log()` will output `[]` instead of `undefined`.

```
let data_e = [];

d3.dsv(" ",filename, (event)=>{
  // your code
})

console.log(data_e);
```

Actually, I could not find a manual about how to get a trigger when `d3.dsv()` is finished. But fo the start try it this way. It's not perfect but it's only supposed to show you that it actually works;

```
let filename = 'uploads/testdata.dat';
const data_e = new Array();

// run the filter
d3.dsv(" ",filename, (event)=>{
    data_e.push(event.mass);
})

// wait 2 seconds, then show the array in the console
setTimeout( () => {
    console.log(data_e);
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Uhm I have tried that but I'm not sure that's the issue. Only difference is that now I get an array of arrays `Array []
​
0: Array ["734.770828169"]
​
1: Array["85.0912893849"]
... `

Comment: That's creepy. Just one more analysis, please. Please, provide the output of `console.log(JSON.stringify(event.mass))`.  If it gets to long you can shorten the string. Important are the first 200 characters or so. Just to understand the structure better.

Comment: Edited with that output!

Comment: Okay, so your problem is, that d3 runs asynchronously. I posted your a solution just to show that you data is actually available outside. But not at the time when your `console.log()` is fired. Please, try my demo. You'll see that it works. It is not perfect but a start.

Comment: Oh, that's fair! At least it's a good start to make things a bit more clear. Thank you very much!